# Rooting an oppo a53s using a rooted .ozip as an update file

Tags: android, root, oppo

I have a problem, when I start my oppo after having been turned off the bootanimation does not appear, but after a while the phone turns on, as if the bootanimation does not exist, in the same way when I start the bootloader or the recovery mode it does not appear, instead the The phone vibrates and within a while it starts normally, as if instead of opening the bootloader it started

I was thinking of using a mode that oppo has that lets you update your phone with a .zip or .ozip.
The ozip of the phone has a boot.img inside and i was thinking of changing that boot.img to one rooted by magisk, will my phone be root after the update?